# Connect Android emulator to network, but not host?

Tags: networking, android-emulator, wifi, android-wifi, genymotion

## Setup

```
[Android Emulator (or Genymotion)] ---> [Host (Windows 7)] ---> Wi-Fi enabled camera
```

## Problem

The [Wi-Fi enabled camera](https://theta360.com/) only accepts Wi-Fi connection from *exactly one* client.

## Question

*How can I configure the Android Emulator (or Genymotion) to connect to the camera without the host connecting to the camera?*

Note: I have a USB Wi-Fi adapter at hand, but I doubt that the emulator (or Genymotion) has drivers to use that directly.

Answer (score 0):

What I did, and what works at least with my camera:

The camera assigns the client always IP 192.168.1.15. So, I gave the host (Windows 7) a static IP that is different: 192.168.1.16. Now, when the Android emulator connects via the bridge, then it gets 192.168.1.15. The host on 192.168.1.16 is ignored by the camera.

If there is a general purpose solution, I'd like to hear about it.